# Luhn Failed IMEI Number Required

Tags: c#, luhn

I was in the middle of implementing the `LUHN` Check functionality into my application, but i just stuck in the developer testing. I was not able to find a valid `IMEI` number whose `LuHN` check must be failed. Please guys provide me the one. I know its not a technical question, but its really important to test the functionality.

Comment: Can't you just change a digit on a valid one?

Comment: sounds good to me, i will do it and let you know...

Comment: Bit of a silly question but how do you know if you've implemented the functionality properly if you don't know what an invalid range is? Are you relying on someone telling you an invalid range in order to create a unit test for it?